# Best way to start audio programming?

Tags: audio, asio

I want to start programming a synthesizer. I reckoned that I would need to use the sound card, so I started to google. After a while, discovered many options:
  - WaveOut API - I've heard that this one is outdated, so I scrapped this one.
  - WASAPI - Seemed a little bit too low level for what I wanted.
  - DirectSound, XAudio, XAudio2 - Seem reasonably fine, but I want to have as little latency as possible.
  - Asio - Seemed like exactly what I want!

I did find a couple of tutorials and source code to get me started on audio programming. Sadly, the [only one I got to work](http://www.tmsoft.com/tutorial-sound.html) uses the waveOpen API, which I don't want to use.

Then I found [this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24536/Low-Latency-Audio-using-ASIO-Drivers-in-NET), which seemed perfect for my needs.
This tutorial is, suprisingly, the only usable (well, not that usable since I can't get it to work) resource I can find on using ASIO. Thing is, I can't get it to work. When I run the demo I get a 'Application has stopped working'-error, followed by the console output:

> Unhandled Exception: System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'BlueWave.Interop.Asio, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. File name: 'BlueWave.Interop.Asio, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'   at BlueWave.Interop.Asio.Test.TestConsole.Main(String[] args)
>
> WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1. Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging. To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

When I try to compile, I got a whole lot of <strike>Rosie</strike> errors:
[image: the errors I get, duh]

This is after I manually placed msvcr90.dll and msvcd90.dll in C:\Windows\System32 (I couldn't get them to install any other way). Ow yeah, and of course I installed ASIO4ALL before all this.

So, this is not really a question, but I'm merely asking for general advice. I think it shouldn't be THAT hard to get asio working, but at the same time a link to another resource for learning the ASIO API would be great, as well as any other advice. (Maybe it's easier to just go and try to get Xaudio2 working? I don't know...)

Thanks in advance, and sorry if you think my question is a long or boring read!

EDIT: Thanks for the reactions. I have come across the [ASIOHost API by TropicalProgrammer](http://www.tropicalcoder.com/ASIOHostDLL.htm). No idea if it's any good, but it looks promising. I'm looking into it currently. There may be better options, but I have to admit that I got my mind set on ASIO currently.

Comment: Maybe I should send Steinberg a mail and ask if they have any resources for the API. I couldn't find any in their knowledge base or on their forums.

Comment: Ow, I already saw this, but I forgot again, silly me.
Steinberg HAS a API guide, which comes in the SDK download, but is also available [online](http://www.scribd.com/doc/14562218/9-ASIO-SDK-21). I haven't really used it, since it is only about the API (and that's not where my problem is).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest having a look at [Juce](http://rawmaterialsoftware.com/juce.php) which is a dual-licensed audio framework for writing both audio plug-ins and host applications.  Quite a few commercial applications have been built using it.

Since your objective is to build a synthesiser, the path of least resistance is to build it as a VST plug-in.  JUCE provides a host application that takes care of managing the OS's audio APIs, good documentation and numerous examples.  All you will need to do is implement the render-callback for your synth.

As for ASIO, a great many pro-audio applications have been built with it, mainly because of the traditional shortcomings of the normal audio APIs on successive versions of Windows - particularly where latency or high channel-count is concerned.  On Windows, ASIO uses dedicated drivers for the audio hardware and bypasses the host operating system's audio stack.  I suspect Juce will take care of this for you.

Comment: `+1` It's not worth the effort to build your synth as a standalone application.  Make it a VST/AU/(whatever Linux uses) so people can use your synth in the music software of their choice.  Plus you will get MIDI, automation, recording, and effects for free.

Comment: @japreiss Seems that it's VST all the way on Linux (on x86 at least) using the Windows version of plug-ins.   There are numerous other plug-in APIs used on Linux, but nobody releases commercial plug-ins for them.

Comment: using WINE for the MSVCRT dependency?

Comment: @japreiss Quite likely - although there really aren't many symbols to fix up in a VST, and the host application provides quite a lot of the services a plug-in would need.

Answer (score 0):

Not a really helpful answer, but I decided to go with XAUDIO2. I wouldn't really say it's easy to use, but at least there are tutorials available (I use [this one](http://www.win32developer.com/tutorial/xaudio/xaudio_tutorial_1.shtm), but microsoft has a serie available as well).

Comment: Didn't work out, went with waveOut instead.

Comment: First experiment (finally) worked out. Source and project files can be found on http://www.mediafire.com/?m5kxe6h3b3lh7d9

Comment: Performance is very bad on older computers. I'm giving WASAPI a go...